# Input negative value to input type number with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a test that would give me a warning about negative value that I've inputted to the field, but I can't make a negative input. The field after each try goes back to "1" and doesn't give any warning. The code of the input:

```
<input numbersonly="" trim="blur" type="number" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched">
```

At this point I've tried

- direct input (send_keys),
- changing attribute "value",
- changing attribute "valueAsNumber",
- emulate scroll down (because this input allows this action from user),
- click on decrement button by offset (because there are no locators for these buttons),
- changing the class name to invalid (because it happens after inputting negative number as user),
- changing the class type to text (the restrictions for values remains with that).

Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: _The field after each try goes back to "1"_: Can you set -1 manually?

Comment: No, when I try to make it by hand, it goes to 0 and I can't input "-"